# Ubuntu installation stuck

Tags: system-installation

I'm installing ubuntu unity 14.10 and the installation process seems to be stuck. The last line says:
[...] evm: HMAC attrc: 0x1
There is no change since about two hours.

I'm using a laptop ASUS PRO61S 
with Windows Vista
and graphic card NVIDIA Geforce GT 120M.

1) Is the installation still running?
2) How can i cancel the installation process without damaging any of the older data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try by opening the new Terminal and use the below command hope this will clean up all the data's which we have installed,

```
echo "Cleaning Up"

sudo apt-get -f install 

sudo apt-get autoremove 

sudo apt-get -y autoclean 

sudo apt-get -y clean
```